# Use 2 or more url for a single HTML Page

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've an important question regarding Node Express. I've a single html page which has been divided into three div with ids (login-form, signup-form and forgot-password). Now, I want that I use different url for every div. How can I do that in node express?

```js
let forgot_password_enable = document.querySelector('#forgot')
let signup_form_enable = document.querySelector("#signup")
let login_form_enable1 = document.querySelector("#login-enable")
let login_form_enable2 = document.querySelector("#go-login")

let forgot_password_form = document.querySelector("#forgot-password")
let login_form = document.querySelector("#login-form")
let signup_form = document.querySelector("#signup-form")

//Enable forgot password form using "Forgotton Password?". 
forgot_password_enable.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (forgot_password_form.style.display != 'none' && signup_form.style.display != 'none' && login_form.style.display != 'none') {
    forgot_password_form.style.display = 'none'
    signup_form.style.display = 'none'
  }
  if (forgot_password_form.style.display == 'none' &&
    signup_form.style.display == 'none' && login_form.style.display != 'none') {
    forgot_password_form.style.display = 'block'
    login_form.style.display = 'none'
  }
})

//Enable Sign-up Form using "Didn't have an account?"
signup_form_enable.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (forgot_password_form.style.display != 'none' && signup_form.style.display != 'none' && login_form.style.display != 'none') {
    forgot_password_form.style.display = 'none'
    signup_form.style.display = 'none'
  }
  if (forgot_password_form.style.display == 'none' && signup_form.style.display == 'none' && login_form.style.display != 'none') {
    login_form.style.display = 'none';
    signup_form.style.display = 'block'
  }
})

//Enable Login Form using "Already have an account?"
login_form_enable1.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (forgot_password_form.style.display != 'none' && signup_form.style.display != 'none' && login_form.style.display != 'none') {
    forgot_password_form.style.display = 'none'
    login_form.style.display = 'none'
  }
  if (forgot_password_form.style.display == 'none' && login_form.style.display == 'none' && signup_form.style.display != 'none') {
    signup_form.style.display = 'none'
    login_form.style.display = 'block'
  }
})

//Enable Login Form using "Back to Login Page."
login_form_enable2.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (forgot_password_form.style.display != 'none' && signup_form.style.display != 'none' && login_form.style.display != 'none') {
    login_form.style.display = 'none'
    signup_form.style.display = 'none'
  }
  if (forgot_password_form.style.display != 'none' && login_form.style.display == 'none' && signup_form.style.display == 'none') {
    forgot_password_form.style.display = 'none'
    login_form.style.display = 'block'
  }
})

let email = document.getElementById('email')

email.addEventListener('input', () => {
  emailRegex = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  return emailRegex.test(val);
}, 'Invalid e-mail.');
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/login-signup3.css">
  <title>Login/Register</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h3 id="home"><a href="index.html">Back to Home</a></h3>
  <div class="form-container">
    <!-- To enable the Forgot Password form.
Forgot Password<input type="checkbox" name="forgot_password" id="enable_password">

To enable Login form from Sign-up form.
Login Form<input type="checkbox" name="login" id="login-enable">

To enable Sign-up form from Log-in form
Signup Form<input type="checkbox" name="signup" id="signup-enable">

To enable Login-form when "signup-enable" input box is checked by clicking on the "Already have an account?"
Login Form<input type="checkbox" name="login" id="login-enable2"> -->


    <div id="login-form">
      <form action="#" id="login">

        <!--Username or Email Input.-->
        <div class="usermail">
          <label for="useremail"><img src="../logos and images/username.png" alt="Image not found!"></label>
          <input type="email" name="Email" id="useremail" placeholder="Username or Email" required><b style="color: red;">*</b>
        </div><br>

        <!--Password Input.-->
        <div class="password">
          <label for="password"><img src="../logos and images/password.png" alt="Image not found!"></label>
          <input type="password" name="Password" id="password" required placeholder="Password"><b style="color: red;">*</b>
        </div><br>

        <!--Login and Clear Button, Forgotton Password and Signup-form enable-->
        <div class="log-frgt">
          <input type="submit" value="Log in" id="signin">
          <input type="reset" value="Clear" id="reset">
          <span id="forgot" style="color: royalblue;cursor: default">Forgotton Password?</span>
        </div><br>
        <span id="signup" style="color: royalblue;cursor: default">Didn't have an account?</span>
      </form>
    </div>

    <!--Sign-up Form-->
    <div id="signup-form">
      <form action="" method="POST">
        <!--Name input box.-->
        <div class="name">
          <h4>Name</h4>
          <div class="firstlastname">
            <label for="first-name" style="font-weight: bolder;">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="firstname" id="first-name" placeholder="First Name" required><b style="color: red;">*</b>

            <br><label for="last-name" style="font-weight: bolder;">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="lastname" id="last-name" placeholder="Last Name (Optional)">
          </div>
        </div><br>

        <!--Father Name Input Box.-->
        <div class="father-name">
          <label for="father-name" style="font-weight: bolder;">Father Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="father-name" id="father-name"><b style="color: red;">*</b>
        </div>

        <!--Gender Input-->
        <div class="gender">
          <h4>Gender</h4>
          <!--Male-->
          <label for="male">Male</label>
          <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="Male">

          <!--Female-->
          <label for="female">Female</label>
          <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="Female">

          <!--Third Gender-->
          <label for="other-gender">Other</label>
          <input type="radio" name="gender" id="other" value="Other">
        </div>

        <!--Username Input.-->
        <div class="username">
          <label for="username"><img src="./logos and images/username.png" alt="Image not found!"></label>
          <input type="text" name="Username" id="username" placeholder="Choose your Username" required><strong style="color: red;">*</strong>
        </div><br>

        <!--Email Input.-->
        <div class="email">
          <label for="email"><img src="./logos and images/username.png" alt="Image not found!"></label>
          <input type="email" name="Email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your Email" required><strong style="color: red;">*</strong>
        </div><br>

        <!--Password & Confirm Password Input Box.-->
        <div class="password">
          <!--Password-->
          <label for="password"><img src="../logos and images/password.png" alt="Image not found!"></label>
          <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Create Password" required><b style="color: red;">*</b>
        </div><br>

        <!--Confirm Password.-->
        <div class="cnfm-password">
          <label for="cnfm-password"><img src="../logos and images/password.png" alt="Image not found!"></label>
          <input type="password" name="cpassword" id="cnfm-password" placeholder="Confirm Password" required><b style="color: red;">*</b>
        </div><br>

        <!--Mobile Number Input-->
        <div class="mobile">
          <label for="mobile"><img src="../logos and images/mobile.png" alt=""></label>
          <input type="number" name="Mobile_No." id="mobile" placeholder="Enter your Number"><strong style="color: red;">*</strong>
          <input type="submit" value="Send">
        </div><br>

        <!--OTP Input.-->
        <div class="otp">
          <label for="otp" style="font-weight: bold;">OTP</label>
          <input type="number" name="OTP" id="otp" placeholder="Enter your OTP" required><strong style="color: red;">*</strong>
          <input type="submit" value="Verify" id="otp-verify">
        </div><br>

        <!--Sign-up, Clear Button and Log-in form show-->
        <div class="btn-logshow">
          <input type="submit" value="Register" id="register">
          <input type="reset" value="Clear" id="clear">
          <span id="login-enable" style="color: royalblue;cursor: default;">Already have an account?</span>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>

    <div id="forgot-password">
      <form action="#">
        <!--Email Input.-->
        <div class="email2">
          <label for="email2"><img src="../logos and images/" alt="Image not found!"></label>
          <input type="email" name="Email" id="email2" placeholder="Enter Email" style="font-weight: bolder;" required><strong style="color: red;">*</strong>
        </div><br>

        <!--Username Input.-->
        <div class="username2">
          <label for="username2"><img src="./logos and images/username.png" alt="Image not found!"></label>
          <input type="text" name="Username" id="username2" placeholder="Enter Username (Optioal)">
        </div><br>

        <!--Mobile Number Input.-->
        <div class="mobile2">
          <label for="mobile2"><img src="../logos and images/" alt="Image not found!"></label>
          <input type="number" name="Mobile_No." id="mobile2" placeholder="Enter your Number" required><strong style="color: red;">*</strong>
          <input type="submit" value="Send" id="otp_send2">
        </div><br>

        <!--OTP Input.-->
        <div class="otp2">
          <label for="otp2" style="font-weight: bold;">OTP</label>
          <input type="number" name="OTP" id="otp2" placeholder="Enter your OTP" required><strong style="color: red;">*</strong>
          <input type="submit" value="Verify" id="otp-verify2">
        </div><br>

        <!--Password Change Button, Login-form enable and Signup-form enable.-->
        <div>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="pwdchng">
          <span id="go-login" style="color: royalblue;cursor: default">Back to Login Page.</span>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="../JS/login-signupform.js"></script>
  <script src="../Backend/login-signup.js"></script>
</body>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: _"I want that I use different url for every div..."_ – Do you want the submit button of these divs to post response to a different end-point? Or you want to serve the HTML of these divs from a different URL?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to create a new route to handle each request. So in each of your divs, you would make an AJAX request to a distinct route.

1. div1 = post request to "/api/login"
2. div2 = post request to "/api/signup"
3. div3 = post request to "/api/forgotPassword"

And in your Express app, create each distinct route:

```
app.post("/api/login", (req, res) => {
  //handle request, of course you should be using authentication middleware to secure this route
  res.send(res)
})

app.post("/api/signup", (req, res) => {
  res.send(res)
})

app.post("/api/forgotPassword", (req, res) => {
  res.send(res)
})
```

Once your server sends the response to the client, make sure your client side code handles the response and redirects the user to a new route. Of course in this new route, you would have to create a new html page and express route that serves up the static html to them.

Just be sure you're authenticating the routes, and hashing db passwords. You should never store raw text data in your databases! You should be doing hash checks on the db password and user sent pass to verify it.

Comment: How could I add an API? Give me any reference please.

Comment: I mean at this point I'm answering a whole new question. Creating your own NodeJS API is whole task in itself, and if it's doing CRUD operations, there's more configuration to add proper security protocols and setting up database modules. 

Here's a good article you can use to quickly bootstrap a working NodeJS API Server: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_express_framework.htm

Keep in mind, you have to also install Node + NPM and configure your system PATH variables. There's other things, also I suggest installing GIT bash terminal and using that for development. Good luck!